Unity 6 builds an empty folder for WebGL
So basically after updating to Unity 6000.0.29f1, I can't make a build for WebGL platform anymore (it worked fine in 2021 version), since it builds an empty folder. Although there are some errors appearing for 1 second before they disappear (in attachments).
Any thoughts?

No, it doesnt make an empty folder, it fails to build - due to errors, which is expected.  What is less clear is why you're calling Editor functions in the game.

Your Assets/Code/Core/Utils.cs is trying to reference UnityEditor.AddressableAssets. Unity does not compile the UnityEditor namespace into builds, they can only be used from within the editor.
It's possible that your IDE included the using statement (on line 4 or 5) for this namespace without you knowing. If so, you can just remove it and recompile.

If you need this functionality when inside the Unity Editor, wrap the using statement (and the code that uses it) with a preprocessor directive to tell the compiler to only compile the code inside the editor:
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor.AddressableAssets;
#endif

If you need this functionality within a build, you have to find an alternative way to do achieve the same functionality, there's no way to include UnityEditor functionality within builds. But this wouldn't have worked even before upgrading to Unity 6, it's not like the update would have changed anything in that regard.

Or if its not, move the file into an Editor folder, so its only for use in the editor and wont be tried to compile into the game

@BugFinder Or  move it to an Assembly via AssemblyDefinition which is configured to only be compiled for the editor ;)
